# How to login network windows 10 credentials pin

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

My home network has a desktop (Windows 10) and a laptop (w10).  The laptop connects via wifi.
The login screen for the laptop shows "Thomas Matthews" and asks for a PIN.

When I open "My Computer" on the desktop PC ("Heathen"), I can see the laptop ("Renegade").
When I click on the laptop name, I get an "enter network credentials" dialog box.

I use the following User Names and none of them work:
Thomas
Thomas Matthews
"Thomas Matthews"
"\Renegade\Thomas Matthews"

How do I access my network laptop from my desktop?

**Edit 1:** Both the laptop and the desk have multiple users.

Comment: Within PowerShell, type `whoami`, what is the output of this command?  Provide this vital information as a comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

From the Desktop, you need to connect to the Laptop.

**(1) Log into the Laptop**

You can use Windows RDP (will log off the current user) and then log in by a known name.

I assume one of the names you showed will work, but check the users on the Laptop (login into the actual laptop).

You can also install Radmin Server on the Laptop and install Radmin Viewer on the desktop. Radmin will allow to connect to whoever is currently logged in on the Laptop. I use Radmin for its overall flexibility.

In either case above, if logging on, you will need the Laptop password or PIN.

Note: If the company laptop has been constrained, use the Desktop as the target machine and access it from the laptop.

**(2) Map Network Drive**

If you just need to see the network shares, you can do this with Map Network Drive (RDP / Radmin not needed).

net use X:\nameoflaptop\sharedfolder  /user:username password

If you do not enter the password in the script, you will be challenged for it.

Both methods above can use either machine as the target machine - you just have to choose. Once connected you can move files either way.

**I do both:**  Map the other computer's folders to sync data and copy whatever.  Log into other computer to pick up email on it.

**Note:** When connecting to another Windows Machine, you need Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing, and Password Protected Sharing all ENABLED.  WiFi needs to be Private, not Public. Make sure (on your router) Wireless Isolation (if any) is disabled.

Comment: Let me rephrase.  I want to map a network drive on the Desktop to the laptop.  My RDP on the desktop has been modified by my company's IT department. :-(

Comment: I showed the mapping instructions in my answer

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - [Edit] your question. As currently written this answer actually answers your question. The problem you face and reason questions should be detailed before they are submitted is, by clarifying your question, you’ll likely invalidate this answer but it most likely won’t actually answer your real question

Comment: @Thomas Matthews  - I clarified my answer to note that either machine can be the target machine. It may be easier to work from the company laptop because it is constrained. Once connected, you can move files either way.

Comment: "My RDP on the desktop has been modified by my company's IT department." Though it's your home network, if IT has some say in your machine setup, check with them, lest you violate a company rule (e.g.,  by accidentally enabling split tunneling).